# How to iterate over all rows in an Excel Table using OpenPyXL?

Tags: python, openpyxl

The documentation of OpenPyXL for Excel Tables don't mention how to iterate over values in the table (see [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html?highlight=range)).

What would be an effecient way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with the following function to do it.

```
from typing import Any, Dict, Generator

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
from openpyxl.utils import rows_from_range

TableRow = Dict[str, Any]

def iter_table_rows(ws: Worksheet, tb: Table) -> Generator[TableRow, None, None]:
    """Iterate over rows from a table with headers (row as dictionary)"""
    def get_row_values(row_cell_ref):
        return [ws[c].value for c in row_cell_ref]
    
    iter_rows = rows_from_range(tb.ref)
    headers = get_row_values(next(iter_rows))
    
    for row_cells in iter_rows:
        yield {h:v for h,v in zip(headers, get_row_values(row_cells))}


wb = load_workbook("my_file.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

tb = ws.tables["MyTable"]
for row in iter_table_rows(ws, tb):
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the function. I 've added a ws argument, as ws is not a global variable and his required for the get_row_values.

```
def iter_table_rows(ws:Worksheet, tb:Table) -> Generator[TableRow, None, None]:
"""Iterate over rows from a table with headers (row as dictionary)"""
    def get_row_values(ws:Worksheet,row_cell_ref:tuple):
        return [ws[c].value for c in row_cell_ref]

    iter_rows = rows_from_range(tb.ref)
    headers = get_row_values(ws,next(iter_rows))

    for row_cells in iter_rows:
        yield {h:v for h,v in zip(headers, get_row_values(ws,row_cells))}
```

I've not seen other way to do it for the moment.

 And **there is no "parent" attribute to know in which worksheet** is the table.

Well at the end I come to a different solution.

 Here is a code of a function to extract data from a xlsx table in a json file.

 I'm guessing it's more near the philosophy of the openpyxl. Data are stored in worksheet, and table seems to be a kind of pointer to a range. The most efficient way to read data in a worksheet is to use ws.iter_row specifiying the range based on min_row,max_row,min_col,max_col.

```
import json
import logging

from argparse import Namespace

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange

def xlsx_Json(args: Namespace):
    """Extract table values from an excel workbook in a json file

    Args:
        args (Namespace): parsed arguments
        args.workbook   : filename of the excel document
        args.worksheet  : name of the sheet to read
        args.table      : name of a table in worksheet

        args.output     : name of a output file (json format)
    Note:
        It's assumed that table exists in worksheet, and worksheet exists in workbook, and file exists
    """
    #wb = load_workbook(filename=args.workbook,read_only=True)  !!! read only worksheet doesn't have table ?
    wb = load_workbook(filename=args.workbook)
    ws = wb[args.worksheet]
    table = ws.tables[args.table]

    # table.ref needs to be converted in a CellRange, and use the range to read data in the worksheet
    table_range = CellRange(table.ref)
    tableJson={ args.table : [] }
    header=table.column_names

    for nb_rows,row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row=table_range.min_row+1, 
                                         min_col=table_range.min_col, 
                                         max_row=table_range.max_row, 
                                         max_col=table_range.max_col, 
                                         values_only=True )):
        #   min_row=range.min_row+1  skip the header row
    
        #   need to convert row element to string to make a serializablejson object
        #   value such datetime are not directly serializable
        if nb_rows == 0:
            for h,x in zip(header,row):
                logging.info(f"{h}:type-{type(x)}:value:{x}")
        if nb_rows % 100 == 0:
            # print row number every 100 lines
            logging.info(f"rows:{nb_rows}")
        row_Json=dict(zip(header,[str(x) for x in row]))        
        tableJson[args.table].append(row_Json)

    with open(args.json_output,"w") as file_out:
        json.dump(tableJson,file_out,indent=4)

    logging.info(f"{nb_rows} elements written in {args.json_output}")
```

Comment: Interesting idea. For small improvements, 1. why do you use a Namespace? it would be better to have argument names directly (especially if you want to have proper code suggestion, and linting (esp. check of types) 2. usually variables names are lowercase 3. Why using a dictionary for tables when you just have one table? 4. This code is cool but you could simplify by leveraring the power of pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html (arguments `sheet_name`, `usecols`, `skiprows`, and `nrows`)

Comment: and indeed, I should have added `ws` argument in my function: I will update